# jalali Calendar for dateTimepicker jquery ui plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, calendar

I am using [dateTimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) plugin for datepicker widget jquery ui.

Now I want to add jalali Calendar support to it.

Of course an alternate and customized version of datepicker jquery ui is written that you can see at [jalali date picker](http://hasheminezhad.com/datepicker).

that works very well but when I use **datetimepicker** and  **jalali date picker** ,a problem occurs.

If you know, in jalali calendar and gregorian calendar are some differences on day month length . for Example **February** month(2nd month in year) in Gregorian have 28 days while **Ordibehesh** (2nd month in jalali) have 31 days.

When attach both jalali datepicker and datetimepicker to page and call **datetimepicker** provided by dateTimepicker plugin, days shown are correct But when click(select) a date from (2nd month of jalali), for example Thirtieth day , 2nd day of third jalali month(named khordad) is returned, why ? because February has 28 month.

it is a jsfiddle Of that I described :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".datePicker").each(function () {
    $(this).datetimepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
     altFieldTimeOnly: false,
     timeFormat: "HH:mm",
     altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
     separator: " ",
     altSeparator: " ",
     altField: $(this).next('.hiddenField'),
     stepMinute: 5
     
    });
   });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24987834/calendar.js"></script>

<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24987834/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc.js"></script>

<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24987834/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc-fa.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/i18n/jquery-ui-timepicker-fa.js"></script>



<input id="start_date_picker" class="datePicker form-control from" targetTo="#end_date_picker" name="start_date_picker" type="text" style="direction:rtl">

<input class="hiddenField" name="start_date" type="hidden">
```

I think that click event attached to datetimepicker have a problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Hours of search and Checking **jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js** and **Jalali datepicker jquery ui** I found that just replace all `new Date()` to `$.datepicker.CDate()` (expect line 262), resolves the problem.